# How to make a dynamic menu part in a cms with infinite submenus in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, content-management-system

I have a question about this topic.
My purpose is designing something like other menus in cms like joomla.
What is your idea about tables in database?
For example there should be a possible way to make infinite submenu. How many tables should I have to have?
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One table should be enough. You give every row a ParentID column and reference the primary ID of the same table. There should be a root node with no pID set.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more?? Thank you.

Comment: What additional questions do you have?
1 table: id, parent_id, name, content, slug, created, updated

Comment: So, as I understood, you mean this:
id,  menu_name  , pid
1    a            1
2    b            1
3    c            2

Result is:
a
 -b
   --c
Yes?

Comment: yes, seems ok, but the first one should be 1 a NULL since it has no parent

Comment: sry, and one more thing. What do you mean by mentioning column 'content' ?

Comment: My implementation was for a document hierarchy which could be displayed in a tree-like fashion. If you only want to build a menu without document content you don't need it.